# Cleveref: Change behaviour of \Cref to use the abbreviated form

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

The journal *International Journal of Solids and Structures* uses always capitalised and abbreviated form of references, i.e. Fig. 1, Eq. 1, even at the beginning of a sentence.

I use the package `cleveref` to adjust this globally.
However, I have not figured it out how to abbreviate a reference at the beginning of a sentence using `\Cref{}`.  I like to stick to `\Cref{}` to be able to change this style in case another journal uses a different style.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  c^2 = a^2 + b^2
  \label{eqn}
\end{equation}

\Cref{eqn} shows an interesting result.
\end{document}
```

Did I overlook an option in the [documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref)?

Current `cleveref` version as of 27.07.2015: **0.19.1**, released May 2014,  http://www.dr-qubit.org/cleveref.html

**Update:** no change in version 0.21 (June 2017)

Comment: The manual states that it's still not regarded to use the abbreviated form at the beginning of a sentence. Perhaps you have to use `\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}` explicitly

Comment: Regarding your edit of the question: You can always contact the package author and ask for adding a feature.

Comment: As you mentioned, --- "I think adding this as an option (e.g. `abbrevall`) to cleveref would be better and also easy to add. The functionality is already present for `\cref` ... "---; I couldn't find `abbrevall` as an option in `cleveref` package and also could not find similar thing in documentation. Did you find a clear way to use all abbreviated labels?

Comment: I had redefined the capital version explicitly and did not contact the author to add an option `abbrevall` to the package. As you can see on the website http://www.dr-qubit.org/LaTeX_Cleveref_package.html there is no new release since May 2014. If you miss this as a built-in feature, you can contact the author: see http://www.dr-qubit.org/LaTeX_Cleveref_package.html. Apparently, this feature is worthwhile adding since there are several users who would like to have this.

Comment: Sorry, not going to add this as a package option. In proper written English, abbreviations should not appear at the beginning of a sentence. (Probably other languages too, but that's beyond my expertise.) Throughout (La)TeX, defaults are chosen to encourage proper writing style (cf. default page margins, which get even more complaints but have not been changed). If you want to deliberately introduce poor style into your writing, `cleveref` gives you more than enough rope to hang yourself by setting the formats manually using \Crefname et al. (which can be done globally in a cleveref.cfg file).

Comment: @Hotschke would you like to post a self-answer with the content of the update?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin: done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the (deleted) answer and comment by @Christian Hupfer and my own search, there are three possibilities:

1. `\renewcommand{\Cref}[1]{\cref{#1}}`
   This does not work together with the poorman option
2. Replace `Cref` by `cref`, e.g. with
   `$ sed 's/\\Cref{/\\cref{/g' manuscript.tex > manuscript-new.tex`
3. Defining the capital labels for figure, equation, tabular, etc. explicitly (my pick):

   ```
   \Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}
   \Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
   \Crefname{tabular}{Tab.}{Tabs.}
   ```

Note, the package author of cleveref is not going to add this as a package option (e.g. `abbrevall`) since this is considered poor writing style (see comment by Toby Cubitt).

Comment: This is a bit unfortunate: [IEEE requires so (page 19)](http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE_Style_Manual.pdf).

Comment: You could also contact Toby Cubitt the author of cleveref. Maybe he reconsiders it when many major publisher ignore the rule of no abbreviation at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: Your solution works well for me. What about "Section" "Sections"? What is an appropriate abbreviation "Sect." "Sects."? So the command would be `\Crefname{section}{Sect.}{Sects.}` ?

Comment: I also needed `\Crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tabs.}`.

Comment: Do you need `~` and `.` to say that `.` is not a period? For example, `\Crefname{section}{Sect.~}{Sects.~}`.